# Is it reasonable to rely on Android 3.0 and drop previous versions?

Tags: android

I am new to Android dev and it seems there is a thousand Android versions variations out there in users hands.

A lot of Android features (Fragments for example) are available on Android 3.0+. From a marketshare perspective, is it reasonable to develop an app for Android 3.0+ and abandon the users that use older versions of Android, or does it mean 50% of Android device users will not be able to use the app?

Comment: It is not reasonable; nor, in your case, justified because there is a support library that you can add to your project to have much of the functionalities and especially fragments to versions prior of 3.0

Comment: It's a personal choice.  My latest app only supports Android 4.0.3+.  I know I'm excluding 50% of the Android users and that's ok with me.  By the time I actually release it (if ever) it'll be far less than 50% exclusion anyway.

Comment: Jake Wharton is the person who solved this problem specially ABS....hats off...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2.3 is by far the largest in use release.
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

47.7%, seems like too big of a group to exclude outright to me.

Comment: This chart only accounts for % of visitors to Play store. Unfortunately, it doesn't account for % of revenue spent in play store. Based on advertising rates, I expect the numbers to be very different: http://info.tapjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Tapjoy-Insights_Issue4_Final.pdf

Answer (score 2):

2.3 accounts for **a lot of the market** in terms of people: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.

But 2.3 **doesn't account for a lot of potential revenue** (consider how much advertisers value different types of users: [tapjoy study](http://info.tapjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Tapjoy-Insights_Issue4_Final.pdf)). After all, 2.3 users have either cheaper phones or don't bother to buy newer phones.

Moreover, supporting 2.3 requires **much more effort**. If you support 2.3, then you need to do the following:

- Compatibility libraries, if you want to be able to use features like Fragments to support tablets
- Support more than one theme, since Holo theme is only on 4.0+ (which you *need* to use, if you want an attractive app)
- Don't get to use the convenient Property Animation framework, and other awesome new frameworks

Answer (score 1):

2.3 ppl are cheaper than 4.0 ppl.

Are you selling your app? Maybe you are trying to build a large userbase with the intention of charging later down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on fragemnts and use the formal compatibility package to add support for Android 1.6+

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

The OS update rate on Android is lower than on iOS and more people walk around with old Android versions. In many cases they are simply unable to update their OS since their device manufacturer does not release an official update.

Answer (score 0):

The Support Library and ActionBarSherlock can get your app on all relevant versions of Android. Don't drop 2.x support just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Many of Android 3.0+ features are available through [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)
  in addition with [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) You can support older versions of android.